# Vulkan Image View Feature Flags

Tags: vulkan

I get this validation message

```
If a VkSampler created with magFilter or minFilter equal to VK_FILTER_LINEAR and compareEnable equal to VK_FALSE is used to sample a VkImageView as a result of this command, then the image view's format features must contain VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_SAMPLED_IMAGE_FILTER_LINEAR_BIT
```

But I can't see how to set the image view format features.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you that you're using a linear sampler (magFilter or minFilter is VK_FILTER_LINEAR) to sample from an image view whose format doesn't have the VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_SAMPLED_IMAGE_FILTER_LINEAR_BIT feature.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Use a different sampler. If you don't need linear filtering, you can use a point sampler instead.
2. Use a different image view format. If you need linear filtering, you can use a format that supports it.

Comment: OK so I have fixed the validation message.  What I am trying to do is I have an offscreen frame buffer with a red integer attachment.  I am then rendering it to the screen as a second attachment along with the swap chain image.  I pass it into the final shader as a sampled image.  It renders fine in the offscreen buffer but when it gets to the screen buffer the colors are changed.  I render only red to the off screen buffer but in the screen buffer it is more blue.

Comment: @SeanNolan To avoid this, you need to use a format that supports linear filtering for your offscreen framebuffer attachment. For example, VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT supports linear filtering, but VK_FORMAT_R32_UINT does not.

Comment: How do I make a point sampler?

Comment: Figured out my problem.  I was not returning the red value from the shader.  I was trying to return the entire color.